# eslint import/order breaks down when using typescript aliases

Tags: typescript, eslint, alias, eslint-plugin-import

I am using typescript path aliases in a large react project.  So for example, in my tsconfig.json, I specify some path aliases:

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["common/*"],
      "@settings/*": ["settings/*"],
      // other paths
    }
}
```

Ok great, now when I want to import some modules I can uses these aliases.  We are also using eslint, and one of the rules we use is the [`import/order`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md).  It enforces that anything coming out of node_modules should be imported before any local modules.  I like this rule.  Without using my aliases:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SomeDistantComponent from '../../common/components/SomeDistantComponent'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
```

This will throw a linting error, but formatting the file according to eslint will automatically move the formik import above the `SomeComponent` import, which is what I want.

However, when using my aliases, this does ***not*** throw an error:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SomeComponent from '@common/components/SomeComponent'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
```

Its as if the typescript path aliases have tricked the `import/order` rule, and that rule now breaks down.

***Question:*** How can my linter still recognize these aliases paths?  Can I configure the `groups` or `pathGroups` [options](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md#options) of this plugin to properly group and order my aliased local modules to come after my node modules?

### Bonus question:

I don't necessarily need to distinguish between aliased modules and non-aliased modules in terms of order.  For example

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SomeCloseComponent from './SomeCloseComponent'
import SomeComponent from '@common/components/SomeComponent'
import AnotherCloseComponent from './AnotherCloseComponent'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
```

I'd be fine leaving the import order of `SomeCloseComponent`, `SomeComponent`, and `AnotherCloseComponent`, so long as the `formik` import goes before all of them.  Is it possible to put aliased imports at the same 'priority' level of grouping as non-aliased imports, meaning they won't be reordered among themselves, but will all come after node_module imports?

### Edit - making another attempt:

Based on Aviv Hadar's answer, I've tried this in my eslint file:

```js
"import/order": [
      "warn",
      {
        pathGroups: [
          {
            pattern: "@material-ui/**",
            group: "external",
            position: "after"
          },
          {
            pattern: "@/**",
            group: "internal",
            position: "after"
          }
        ],
        pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ["internal", "external", "builtins"],
        groups: [
          "builtin",
          "external",
          "unknown",
          ["internal", "sibling", "parent"],
          "index",
          "object",
          "type"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

This works in that it treats all imports that begin with `@` as internal, and keeps them on the same level as other internal imports.  So this won't cause a warning:

```js
import { Something } from "@some/aliased/path";
import LocalComponent from "../../local";
import { SomethingElse } from "@another/aliased/path";
```

Which is what I want - all internal modules at the same level of grouping, regardless of aliased vs not, or parent/sibling.  However, this *should* show a warning, but it doesn't:

```js
import { Something } from "@some/aliased/path";
import LocalComponent from "../../local";
import { SomethingElse } from "@another/aliased/path";
import { makestyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
```

The last import does begin with `@`, but it is a node_module, and should be at the top of the list.  In retrospect I wish we would have chosen a different alias prefix, but we didn't.  Is there a way to tweak my config to properly interperet node_modules as `external`, and keep them in that group for ordering?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the `pathGroups` property to indicate to `eslint` that the correct position of paths that starts with `@/` is before/after one of the other groups.

I choose to use the `~` symbol instead of `@` to create a difference between importing from my src folder and importing from an external library that starts with `@`, like this one for example:

```js
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Bar from '~/components/Bar'
```

So now my file looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'; // external
import Bar from '~/components/Bar'; // SPECIAL
import {ReactComponent as Logo} from '../logo.svg'; // parent
import './App.css'; // sibling
```

And this is my definition of the `import/order` rule in my `.eslintrc` file:

```json
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "pathGroups": [
          {
            "pattern": "~/**",
            "group": "external",
            "position": "after"
          }
        ],
        "groups": [
          "builtin",
          "external",
          "internal",
          "unknown",
          "parent",
          "sibling",
          "index",
          "object",
          "type"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see, I'm using the `pathGroups` to tell eslint that the proper position of any import that starts with `~/` is `after` the `external` group.

Because each import here belongs to a different group, any change that I will do to this order will result in an ESLint error.

**P.S.**
I had issues at some point with the imports themselves that were resolved after I updated the `eslint-plugin-import` to version `2.23.4`

Comment: So I've got this sort of working.  I had to change `pattern` to `@/**`, which works (which is wierd, because my prefixes are just `@`, not `@/`.  I changed the `group` to `intrernal`, because these are internal modules, and I grouped `["internal", "sibling", "parent"]` so that they can all be on the same level without being reordered.  The issue is that actual node modules that start with `@` are not forced to be at the top.  I have `pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ["internal", "external", "builtins"]` to try to address that, but no luck

Comment: I followed some tips at [Don't get import/order to work correctly with import aliases](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1682), but this seems to be the last hurdle.  We already have the entire codebase using `@` prefixes, (I knew this would be an issue, but some colleagues wanted that prefix), so here I am. How can I get this last part working, where `@`-prefixed external modules are still forced to come before `@`-prefixed internal modules?

Comment: I can't understand if you used the `pathGroups` property.
If so, can you please share exactly which value that you passed it?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you where I'm at with it.  Its close, but has the fatal issue of interpereting external modules that begin with `@` as internal modules.  I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, though I feel it *should* be.

Comment: A few things:
1. I see you added the `pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes`. I read the docs but I still don't understand what this property does.
2. You typed as a pattern: `pattern: "@/**",`. I don't think that this is the correct pattern. the correct pattern should be `pattern: "@common/**"`
3. I tried it doing it in my code base and it didn't work. I don't know why not but I found a way to get over it: instead of using the `@common/anyFolder` path, I typed `~common/anyFolder` path.
a) The TScondig recognized it.
...

Comment: b) ESlint recognized it and gave appropriate errors if it was placed in the wrong order.
c) Easier to visually see a difference between external modules like `@material-ul` and local absolute imports like `~common/anyFolder`.

Comment: Finally got a chance to try this in another project where I had more liberty to adjust the alias prefixes.  Works perfectly.  Sorry for the long delay, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have aliases like `~const/` and `~helpers/`. I was able to get it to work using this pattern:

```
{
    "pattern": "~*/**",
    "group": "external",
    "position": "after"
}
```

It is a wild card for anything that starts with `~`, and any directory or file within in.